# Is obj/debug in a VisualStudio project, a temporary location?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

In brief, I have a separate WCF VisualStudio Project, to compile the  CLient and Contract dlls. Once I build the project using MS-BUILD(command line), i have a post-build nant task to copy over the Client and Contract dlls to another location.

Now it is easier for me to pick these dlls from obj/Debug folder(as they have only the CLient and Contract dlls and not their dependencies).

However I've heard that the obj/Debug folder is temporary.. and we need to rely on bin/Debug to get the dlls.

Is it necessary to pick it up from bin/debug and not obj/Debug and why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The role of obj\Debug is an undocumented implementation detail of MSBuild.  It exists because MSBuild likes to conditionally copy files based on project settings.  The exact rules are convoluted, to put it mildly, you could only gain insight by studying the .targets files in the framework directory.  Which in themselves are highly dependent on the .NET version you target.

If you really want to know what makes it tick then *do* copy files from obj\Debug and see what hits the fan.  Do beware that this may happen long after you created the project so there will forever be a cast of FUD when builds fail or produce the wrong file.  If that doesn't sound very productive, it is not, then avoid breaking the warranty and copy from the project's output directory.  bin\Debug and bin\Release by default.  If *that* produces a problem then at least you can ask a question about it at SO.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You are supposed to pick up binaries from `bin/Debug`, or the variable `OutputPath` in MSBuild context more specifically,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629394.aspx

Comment: What if Microsoft decides it will not use `obj/Debug` tomorrow? Only `OutputPath` is a reliable contract between you and Microsoft according to the document.

Comment: If all your script is using MSBuild, I will recommend `OutputPath`, but I am not sure what can be the best practice for NAnt/MSBuild interoperation.